# Google Drive API v3, is there anyway to list of files and folders from a root folder?

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api

Looking at the V3 api, `files.list` is able to list folders with `q = mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder'` but it doesn't state if the folders are children of any of the other folders. Is there any endpoint or query that can provide the everything within a root folder be it children files or children folders? So I can use `mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder' and 'root' in parents` to list down all folders within my drive which is the first step for my use case. Subsequently, I want to be looping through each of the folders and find any subfolders and files within the parent folder.

```
Folder A
|-- File A
|-- Folder B
    |-- File B
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

- You want to retrieve files and folders in the root folder using the search query.

If my understanding is correct, how about this answer?

#### Pattern 1:

You want to retrieve the folders in the root folder, you can use the following query.

```
mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder' and 'root' in parents
```

- You can test this at [Try this API](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list?hl=ja&apix_params=%7B%22q%22%3A%22mimeType%20%3D%20%27application%2Fvnd.google-apps.folder%27%20and%20%27root%27%20in%20parents%22%7D).

#### Pattern 2:

You want to retrieve the files and folders in the root folder, you can use the following query.

```
'root' in parents
```

- You can test this at [Try this API](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list?hl=ja&apix_params=%7B%22q%22%3A%22%27root%27%20in%20parents%22%7D).

#### Note:

- With only the search query, all files and folders under the specific folder including the subfolders cannot be retrieved. In this case, it is required to prepare the script for retrieving them. Please be careful this.

#### References:

- [Files: list](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list)
- [Search for Files](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/query-ref)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the direction you want, I apologize.

Comment: This still list all the folder and file within the main drive. Is there any way I can list just the subfolder and files within a folder without a script? I've updated the question to provide more info

Comment: I've messed around with the API more and manage to figure out that the query is still similar but changed to `'{folder id}' in parents` which will list down all subfolder and files within the main folder. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: @Ryan Tin Thank you for replying. In the current stage, there are no methods for directly retrieving all files and folders under the specific folder including the subfolders with only the search query without using the script. But as your latest replying, you can retrieve the files and folders just under the specific folder using `'###' in parents`. In above search query, `root` of `'root' in parents` means the ID of the root folder. So you can retrieve files and folders in the folder with `'{folder id}' in parents`. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/query-ref)